# Jquery formData submit previous files input if no current input is specified

Tags: jquery

Jquery formData submit previous files input if no current input is specified.

I have tried formData.reset() or formData.delete('image'). All not working. Please help.

var globalVariable;
var formData = new FormData();

```
function editPost(pk) {

    if (pk) {
        globalVariable = pk
        post_pk = "#post-" + pk;
        content = $(post_pk).find(".postContent")[0].innerText

        $('#content-id').val(content);

    }
}




$("#updateModal").submit(function () {
    formData.append('contentInput', $('#content-id').val())
    formData.append('pk', globalVariable)
    formData.append('image', $('#image-id')[0].files[0])
    formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}')

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "posts:update-post" %}',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function (res) {
            $('#updateModal').modal('toggle');
            $("#post-" + res.pk).find(".postContent").text(res.content);
            $("#post-" + res.pk).find(".postImage").attr("src", res.image);

        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ":" + xhr.responseText)
        }
    })

    return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`reset()` need to be called against the form & not form data. You can reset a form using one of the below options. Assuming `updateModal` is your form id.

```
//Using Jquery
$("#updateModal")[0].reset(); 

//Using Pure Js
document.getElementById("updateModal").reset();
```

Comment: I am using FormData(), not a typical form.

Comment: It is FormData()

Comment: @BanPeiLim Can you update you html as well to the question